# Openssl Public\Private key Cross OS Platform Support

Tags: java, public-key-encryption, private-key, public-key

Question 1) Can we use the public/Private keys generated on One Operating system (Linux) to Another Operating system (MacOS or Windows)?

Question 2) Does having different version of OpenSSL on different operating system will cause any issue while using the key generated on other Operating system?

I am generating the Public/private Key using OpenSSL::

Encrypted version

````
To generate an encrypted version of private key, use the following command:

```openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -out rsa_key.p8```

To generate an encrypted version of public key, use the following command:

```openssl rsa -in rsa_key.p8 -pubout -out rsa_key.pub```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it anywhere and openssl version should not be a problem. Those keys are using standard called [PKCS 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_8), operating system is irrelevant.